# Concatenate quotes php and javascript function in jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: <?php echo base_url().'index.php/user_management/manage_users/ViewProfile/'?>"+JSON.parse(item.UserID),
    success: function(output_string){
        $('.second_column_content_container').html(output_string);
    }
});
```

I want the result of the url to be enclosed in single or double quotes;
e.g

```
'url: <?php echo base_url().'index.php/user_management/manage_users/ViewProfile/'?>"+JSON.parse(item.UserID)' or 
"url: <?php echo base_url().'index.php/user_management/manage_users/ViewProfile/'?>"+JSON.parse(item.UserID)"
```

Comment: `+JSON.parse(item.UserID)`? What are you trying to achieve with this?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
url: "<?php echo base_url().'index.php/user_management/manage_users/ViewProfile/'?>"+JSON.parse(item.UserID),
//---^^--here
```

or

```
url: "<?php echo base_url() ?>"+'index.php/user_management/manage_users/ViewProfile/'+JSON.parse(item.UserID),
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>'+'index.php/user_management/manage_users/ViewProfile/'+JSON.parse(item.UserID),
    success: function(output_string){
       $('.second_column_content_container').html(output_string);
    }
});
```

instead php concatenation `.` use javascript concatenation `+`.